# REGEX match string include content inside optional delimiter

Tags: regex, string, parentheses

I am trying to match a string using regex and I am very close to having it working the way I want.

Lets say I have a string 5A(test1),4B,3C(test2)

The first thing I do is break the string apart on the commas, so i end up with 3 strings in an array

- 5A(test1)
- 4B
- 3C(test2)

Now I want to pull the following information out; the digit, the letter and the content in the parentheses.  But the parentheses are optional.

Here is my pattern 
`([1-9][0-9]*)([AaBbCcIiFfPpSs]+)(\(.*\))?`

This works except that it includes the parentheses.  so i get
5 A  (test1)
when what i want is
5 A test1

Ive also tried 
`([1-9][0-9]*)([AaBbCcIiFfPpSs]+)\(([^)]*)\)?`
But this doesn't match on the strings without the parentheses so
5A(test1) and 3C(test2) match but 4B does not.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex a bit:

```
([1-9][0-9]*)([AaBbCcIiFfPpSs]+)(\((.*)\))?
```

The content inside `()` will be in capturing group 4.

If your language supports non-capturing group `(?:pattern)`:

```
([1-9][0-9]*)([AaBbCcIiFfPpSs]+)(?:\((.*)\))?
```

This will prevent unnecessary capturing (saves some memory), and the content inside `()` will be in capturing group 3.

Comment: Your second answer does seem to process faster on the server (running in Perl) SO thanks, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You need an additional non capturing group around the optional last part

```
([1-9][0-9]*)([AaBbCcIiFfPpSs]+)(?:\(([^)]*)\))?
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33ved)